# Calling stored procedure from node js

Tags: sql-server, node.js, express, stored-procedures, ejs

I am using express and I am trying to call LoginMember stored procedure from Azure portal. This is my form from, taken from ejs:

```
<form method="post" action="/available-copies">
      <input type="text" placeholder="SSN" name="userssn">
      <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="userpassword">
      <input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

This is my post request

```
router.post('/available-copies', function (req, res) {
    var ssn = req.body.userssn;
    var password = req.body.userpassword;

    sql.connect(sqlConfig, function (err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
        // create Request object
        var request = new sql.Request();
        // query to the database and execute procedure
        request.query("exec LoginMember @SSN='"+ssn+"', @PASSWORD='"+password+"';", function (err, recordset) {
            if (err) console.log(err);

            res.send(recordset);
        });
    });
    sql.close()
});
```

SqlConfig comes from another file and this part is fine. Just in case, this is my stored procedure creation code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE LoginMember @SSN varchar(11), @PASSWORD char(64)
AS
BEGIN
   Select * from Member
   WHERE Member.ssn = @SSN AND Member.password = @PASSWORD
END
```

What happens- When I submit my form, page keeps loading for 3-5mins, after that I get

```
This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
```

Console doesn't return any additional errors. **I know this might be not the best solution I can be using, but this is my approach and I want to make it work.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you are closing sql connection after query execution or failure.What i found in your code is that you are closing sql connection outside sql.connect which is incorrect because node js is asynchronous in nature which is killing your connection before completion.Please find the update code below:

```
router.post('/available-copies', function (req, res) {
var ssn = req.body.userssn;
var password = req.body.userpassword;

sql.connect(sqlConfig, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    // create Request object
    var request = new sql.Request();
    // query to the database and execute procedure 
    let query = "exec LoginMember @SSN='" + ssn + "', @PASSWORD='" + password + "';";
    console.log(query)
    request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            sql.close();
        }
        sql.close();
        res.send(recordset);

    });
  });
});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work, so I guess my issue was that I was closing my connection in incorrect place?

Comment: yes, alway close or release connection inside the execution function after it's success or failure

Comment: One more fast question, is there a way to console.log() my whole query that I am passing? To see what actually gets send to the sql server?

Comment: just set you query string which you are passing in request.query to a variable and log that variable and pass it to request.query
for example:

let query = "exec LoginMember @SSN='" + ssn + "', @PASSWORD='" + password + "';";
console.log(query);
request.query(query, function (err, recordset) {

Answer (score 1):

In this example, I've used `request.execute()` method insted of using `request.query()` to call the procedure.

Just remember that while calling the procedure we have to add `cloumn_name` it's `data_type` and the `key_value` which we are using to compare with.

For that we have to use `request.input()` method, here I am calling a procedure called `GetLedgerBalance` as an example.

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE GetLedgerBalance(
    @c_id VARCHAR(MAX) 
)
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT ledgerBalance 
    FROM clients
    WHERE c_id = @c_id
END
```

In this procedure now we are declaring a variable for `key_value` which is `user_id`

```
let user_id = "C00008";

//calling stored procedure   
sql.connect(config).then(() => {
    const request = new sql.Request();

    request.input("c_id", sql.VarChar, user_id);

    request.execute("GetLedgerBalance").then((result) => { 
        const ledgerBalance = result.recordset[0].ledger_balance;
        console.log(`Ledger Balance is: ₹ ${ledgerBalance}/-`);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(`Error executing sp ${err}`);
    });
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Please consider it for `mssql` module maybe there should be some differences in another modules