# How to call stored procedure from react

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, stored-procedures

I have been given a website that is already developed in ASP.NET. I am required to develop the same in React.

Below is the code in .net written to call a stored procedure when the user clicks login:

```
Dal objDal = new Dal();
DataSet ds = objDal.ByText("AuthenticateUser_RPOS", txtUserId.Text.ToString().Trim() + "|" + txtPwd.Text.ToString().Trim() + "|" + AuthPwdOIM);

if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
{
   <....some code>
}
```

`AuthenticateUser_RPOS` is the name of the stored procedure being called.
I am not familiar with .NET and I have just started doing react. I have searched the internet but couldn't find anything relatable.

So, is there a way to call stored procedure directly in react?

Answer (score 1):

After browsing through web for plenty of days, I could conclude that we cannot call SP from react frontend directly but we can use express middleware to do the job.

For people who stumble upon this problem in future, check this SO post [Calling stored procedure from node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50697134/calling-stored-procedure-from-node-js)